# Custom output path in webpack when I know the specific entry path

Tags: webpack

I am configuring storybook's entry and output in webpack, this means I can't do structural changes and only *add* stuff on top of it.

The entry is just an array. This is how I am adding my own entry:

```js
    config.entry.push(
      path.join(
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
        './node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js'
      )
    );
```

It has no key, but I know the path.
So with only knowing the path, how would I change the output of this specific path? The default output is

`'[name].iframe.bundle.js'`

and I want it to be

`'[name].js'`

I have checked webpack's docs, but didn't find a solution to what I am looking for.

I have found this snippet, but when console logging `pathData` it doesn't give me a lot of information...

```js
    config.output.filename = (pathData) => {
      console.log('THE PATHDATA:', pathData);
      return '[name].iframe.bundle.js';
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation forbids from manipulating the Webpack `entry` and `output` path. Further, since it is using an array based config instead of object (key-value) config for specifying the `entry`, Webpack is going to generate only one bundle i.e. one file.

So, even if you add the path using `config.entry.push`, it is **ever** going to generate only one build file and your pushed file would simply be **appended** to it. So, logically there is no incentive to provide a custom function for `config.output.filename`. The function would be executed for whole chuck only once. That is also the reason why `pathData` doesn't provide which file it is operating on. It is operating on **entry** where each entry can one 1 or 1000+s files by the virtue of importing dependencies.

On the other hand, I can guess that you are trying to bundle a part of your code as a library (excluding storybook related code) that you want to publish or use somewhere else. If that is the case then, I recommend creating a separate Webpack configuration with a different filename.

Typically, you would create three files:

1. `./webpack.common.js` - Create your common configuration that you wish to share between library bundling and storybook bundling. It would have common plugins and loaders.
2. `.storybook/main.js` - Where you customize Webpack for running storybook. It should import your custom configuration defined in `webpack.common.js` and merge with Storybook Webpack configuration
3. `./webpack.lib.js` - This is where you create a configuration dedicated to bundling the library or other special bundling needs. Again, import common loaders and plugins from `webpack.commmon.js` file.

> On a side note, if you are bundling a library, I highly recommend using **Rollup.js**. Use Rollup.js for libraries and Webpack.js for applications.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. The issue I am having is related to a library that I am using, Storybook throws errors because of it. Related: https://github.com/react-pdf-viewer/react-pdf-viewer/issues/847 || https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853837/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-in-storybook-when-working-with-pdfjs-dist || I don't want to create a library myself.